# Is it possible to use DOMDocument::load() function to load an rss feed that is an ashx file?

Tags: php, xml, rss, domdocument

I'm trying to load the contents of what should be an rss feed in a .ashx file on a client's site. I'm not sure if this is possible. Here is the code I'm using.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($client_url);
echo htmlentities($doc->saveXML());
```

All that is being echoed is `<?xml version="1.0"?>` which I believe is being created from the saveXML() function.

Any help?

Thanks,
Caleb

Comment: Why don't you just try? As far as URLs are concerned, there is no file-extension, just the protocol. And for trying, it's best to make error messages and warnings visible btw.

Comment: Makes sure you set the proper namespaces too.

Comment: About error messages, this Q&A might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14504459/367456

Comment: @hakre 1. I have tried. 2. Could it be possible that the feed is created when you hit that page? I guess I need a better understanding of the load function.

Comment: try saving the file locally first to discard problems with the network or php [`allow-url-fopen`](http://php.net/allow-url-fopen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem thanks to hakre and looking at the errors. The problem was that I was using 'https' in  $client_url when I should use 'http'.

Thanks for the advice in turning on my error messages. I think this will be very useful in the future as well.